# Angular - Pikaday: change date in pickaday element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, pikaday

I am using [Angular-Pikaday](https://github.com/nverba/pikaday-angular) directive, Selecting and retrieving date works fine. The value in pikaday input element changes properly when selected from pikaday datepicker.

I want to change value in the pikaday input element via code ie from controller on some action.

I have tried assigning ng-model, it changes value but it is not recognized by pikaday datepicker.

Link to [Plunker](http://goo.gl/BzMwOH)

How can i change value in pikaday input element.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `setDate` method on the objected passed to `pikaday` config.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['pikaday']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.startDate = '11/18/2015';

  $scope.changeDate = function() {
    $scope.startDate.setDate('11/15/2015');
  }
});
```

The above code will work.

**Plnkr** : http://plnkr.co/edit/emdaPPWATDH6JJdV6S4V?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the pikaday-object and call it's `setDate()` method.

As seen in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3gkuM97tGnQkEbCzLpTG?p=preview).

**Edit:**
[VVK's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802999/angular-pikaday-change-date-in-pickaday-element/33803656#33803656) is cleaner.